# Fotorama how to embed an iframe?

Tags: fotorama

Need to add an iframe into the fotorama gallery.

Tab image can be fixed.
Src should be a parameter to pass in.

Note this is on Magento 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get access to the dom element and the api object.

```
// Get the Dom Element.
var $fotorama = jQuery('div.gallery-placeholder > div.fotorama');

// Get the API object.
var fotorama = $fotorama.data('fotorama');
```

Listen for the fotorama:load event and replace the contents with an iframe.

```
// On load handler for fotorama.
$fotorama.on('fotorama:load', function fotorama_onLoad(e, fotorama, extra) {
    if (extra.frame.type === 'iframe') {
        // Replace the contents with the iframe.
        extra.frame.$stageFrame.html('<iframe type="text/html" width="100%" height="100%" src="' + extra.frame.src + '" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen oallowfullscreen msallowfullscreen></iframe>');
    }
});
```

Next up you can push new data for an iframe in like this.

```
fotorama.push({ img: 'iframe.png', thumb: 'iframe.png', 'src': 'http://someurlforiframe', type: 'iframe' });
```

Note: You want to have iframe.png or some other image that is thumbnailed sized ready to load in.

I used an 80x80 one.

I was able to successfully embed 3dvieweronline into the gallery using this code from a template in a custom module with working full screen functionality.

Comment: Hi @liam, 
Your code is working fine, but this will only work with fotoroma:load function,
Can you please help me while working with configurable product as when product load it is working fine, but when i change any color or size attribute change then this video iframe was not coming or not working, as there is already video for that particular color/size option product.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not aware of how it works for configurable products as I only used it on simple products. Would certainly be interested to know if you get it working though @NayanBaraiya
It is likely because each configurable product can have their own images/media. You might be able to use a mixin or some other thing? to change the behavior of when the option changes and the configurable products gallery is set.

Comment: I actually wonder if its possible to replace Fotorama with something else entirely.

Comment: See
app\code\Magento\ConfigurableProduct\view\frontend\web\js\configurable.js

_changeProductImage _addFotoramaVideoEvents

They prepend images. they call gallery.updateData(images)

lib\web\fotorama\fotorama.js
has an updateData method, but no event emitted.
So maybe need to extend configurable.js to do what you want with the adding of the iframe or other things you want to embed depending on the configurable product options/sku.

Comment: Hi @liam, Thanks for the answer, i will try debugging in fotorama.js and let you know.

Comment: @NayanBaraiya How did you get on?